# win7 - batch - Changing number/string in text file

Tags: string, windows, batch-file

I have this short `config.txt` with 2 lines

```
Preamp: 11dB
Include: example.txt
```

Is there a way for batch to find number before `dB` and replace it with either `1 higher` or `1 lower`?

Comment: There are too many ways to count, really.  What have you tried?  Just out of curiosity, this is for Equalizer APO, right?

Comment: yep it is, tried exchanging string but dont really know how to take number as variable, i dont really use batch much

Comment: You read the line and strip away everything but the number.  Easy way to do it would be to use the second token of the line, `11dB`, and set the `d` as the end of line character.  `for /f "usebackq eol=d tokens=2" %%I in ("%configfile%") do if not defined dB set /a dB=%%I + 1` or `- 1`

Comment: I see the idea, but it tries changing db itself not number before, if i understand corectly it tries to makes something like "11 I+1", please advise

Comment: There are lots of existing questions (with answers) here regarding replacing text in files via batch. You've apparently not made any effort to search here first, or you would have located one of those many questions and would have at least an effort to do this yourself in your post. Please do that research now, and come back when you can [edit] your post to include that effort and ask a specific question related to it. Good  luck.

Comment: @c422 Sorry, try `"usebackq tokens=2 delims=:d"` in the `for /F` params.

Comment: @rojo and stephan, thank you for help, at ken i searched but pretty much all anwser tell how to change entire string not read part and modify it, and the ones that actually do show how to replace file name not string part, anyway thank you as well for your contribution.

Comment: @c422 You could `powershell "gc config.txt | %{ [regex]::replace($_, '\d+(?=dB)', {[int]($args[0].value) + 1}) }"` (or `- 1` to decrement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF 
REM read two lines:
<config.txt (
  set /p "line1="
  set /p "line2="
)
REM isolate the number:
set "line1=%line1:* =%"
set "line1=%line1:dB=%"
REM add one:
set /a line1+=1
REM write new file:
>config.txt (
  echo Preamp: %line1%dB
  echo %line2%
)
```

Comment: That's why I am on this site.  You learn a new trick all the time.  That redirection thing is awesome.  +1